# XMarks Safari constantly re-downloads old bookmarks

Tags: safari, data-synchronization, bookmarks

2011 iMac, OSX Mavericks, latest updates.

I have used XMarks (Foxmarks) for years to sync between Chrome and Firefox, but now I'd like to add Opera and Safari to that mix.  Opera works just fine, but Safari refuses to play nicely and I can't figure out why.

I have two profiles, the "default" profile that Foxmarks originally created (mobile.foxmarks.com) and one that I created (Profile 1).  Both have the identical bookmarks in them at this point, as shown in my.xmarks.com.

Unfortunately, Safari keeps somehow finding my old bookmarks from years ago that are a complete mess, and re-downloading them into the browser.  The only positive is that I have disabled Automatic Synchronization in XMark's preferences for Safari, so that Safari will no longer then corrupt my "real" bookmarks in Chrome, Opera, and Firefox, with this ancient data.

My solution every time I notice this (seems to be every few weeks), is to force-download to Safari from the server, overwriting the local data.  This works, but of course kinda defeats the purpose of keeping them all in sync (I browse for different purposes in each browser [different projects] and so would like to be able to bookmark in any of them and know that they will all stay in sync).  Ideally I could let Safari auto-sync as well.

Why does this keep happening?  Where is Safari even getting this old data, since it's clearly not in my profiles on XMarks?  How can I get Safari to stop this and simply work like all the other browsers do with XMarks?

**UPDATE:**

After my most recent re-overwriting of the local bookmarks, I then uploaded from my local machine to the server, overwriting the server bookmrakrs to ensure they should be identical.  A couple hours later I got a popup that says this:

> You restored or uploaded bookmarks from another computer to our
>   servers. You can sync normally (the safest choice), or you can
>   download the server bookmarks, overwriting your local bookmarks. Which
>   do you prefer?

I'm given the choices of Sync, Download, or Cancel.  I took a chance on "Sync" and everything seems fine, I don't see the old bookmarks appearing in Safari.

Comment: Do you have iCloud bookmark sync enabled? I've always had to turn that off to have Xmarks work reliably with Safari.

Comment: I don't even know what that is... I should've also stated I'm on OSX Mavericks, in case it matters.  I'll add that to my question.

Comment: You can check in System Preferences > iCloud. I forget if Safari bookmark sync is on or off by default. (If you're not currently signed into iCloud in this Preferences window, then it shouldn't matter either way.)

Comment: Looks like that must not have been a feature in Mavericks, because it's not there.  There is a "Safari" option though... maybe that's it?  I'm going to disable that in case it is.  I'm sure I don't need Safari backing anything up to iCloud.

Comment: That's probably it -- in Sierra, it's also just a checkbox labelled "Safari". I forget whether it could sync your bookmarks in Mavericks, or just your open tabs, but certainly worth a try.

Comment: Excellent, it's off now so I'll give it a few weeks and see if it happens again.  Feel free to put it as an answer in case it does the trick, and if it does I'll mark it as such once I'm confident.

Comment: So much for that idea.  Safari has once again managed to replace all its bookmarks with my ancient dataset.  No idea how or why.

Comment: Bummer :/ Can't think of anything else to try at the minute, have never really had anything other than the odd glitch with Xmarks over the years.

Comment: It's been overnight, and the bad bookmarks have not reappeared.  I'd like to believe it's because I forcibly overwrote the server data with a good copy of my local data, so in actuality it is re-downloading but it's the same data, so there is no net effect.  But I have no idea if that's true or not.  Will give it a few weeks and see what happens.

Comment: I unfortunately have the same problems here.  iCloud is disabled.  I checked the Log from the Settings menu, but didn't find a clue, that any data comes from the iCloud.  I also exported all my bookmarks and checked that file, which looks fine and corresponds exactly to the bookmarks, I organised in Safari.  Manually deleting all bookmarks in xmarks, reloading the page ... everything ok.  Manually uploading my Safari bookmarks to the server, reloading that page ... BOOM!  Total disaster.  It really it is.  Believe me! :-(

Comment: Did you manually upload your "good" bookmarks from Safari and completely overwrite those on the server?  That's what finally fixed this issue for me.

Comment: @JonathanvanClute: Yes, I completely emptied my bookmarks on the server before manually uploading them again from my computer.  I also made the same experience, after installing Chrome.  When I imported my local Safari bookmarks into Chrome by using the Chrome menu "Import Bookmarks", you can choose to load them from Safari.  It seems, as if the same chaos is loaded, which is uloaded by Safari to the xmarks-server.  If I instead go to safari, export my bookmarks into a file and import that into Chrome, it looks similar to the (organised) booksmarks in Safari.

Comment: @JonathanvanClute (if it fixed it for you, maybe you should answer your own question and mark it solved.)

Comment: Yeah good point, it does seem at this point that it has stayed fixed so... will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have solved my issue, as it's been quite a while now and the problem has not reappeared.

First I turned off Safari XMarks' option to automatically synchronize, so that it wouldn't mess things up during this process.  Then t had to get my bookmarks in Safari all clean & perfect, and once I had that I manually overwrote the server bookmarks with the copy in Safari.  Since then, my old "bad" bookmarks have not reappeared.  I suppose it's possible that Safari is quietly in the background still downloading and overwriting my local with the server bookmarks from time to time, but since the server copy is now correct, *if* that's happening, I don't notice.

Everything seems fine now, I can use/update bookmarks in Chrome and Safari and they all stay in sync, though there is a definite lag in time for them to pick up changes made from one another, that's just a fact of the way the software works it seems.